# multiply the value of precent year to the value of the following year

Tags: sql, sql-server

i would  like to multiply the value of the precedent year to the values of the following year.

this is the data of my table

```
Drop table #Index
Create table #Index
(
  ID int ,
 YearOfMortgrage Smallint,
 Percentage Numeric (10,5)

)

Insert into #Index values ( 1 , 2008    ,1.01000    )
Insert into #Index values ( 2 , 2009    ,1.00125    )
Insert into #Index values ( 3 , 2010    ,1.00200    )
Insert into #Index values ( 4 , 2011    ,1.00850    )
Insert into #Index values ( 5 , 2012    ,1.01400    )
Insert into #Index values ( 6 , 2013    ,1.00900    )
Insert into #Index values ( 7 , 2014    ,1.00450    )
Insert into #Index values ( 8,  2015    ,1.00900    )
Insert into #Index values ( 9 , 2016    ,1.00600    )
Insert into #Index values ( 1,  2017    ,1.00700    )
```

i want to multiply the percentage of 2008 to percentage of 2009 and so on.
like this  1.01000  * 1.00125 * 1.00200 * 1.00850 etc..

i have tried with lag and lead , it seems not working . i could have used function unbounded preceding but it can only used in  agregation .

Any help  will be appreciated , thanks for your time

Comment: What does "seems not working" mean? Could you post the code you have tried already?

Comment: i have tried this solutionSelect Distinct ID,YearOfMortgrage,Convert(Numeric(10,5),CurrentIndex*PreviousIndex) as t,
Percentage
From (

Select ID,YearOfMortgrage,Percentage as CurrentIndex,Percentage,
LAG(Percentage, 1,1) OVER (ORDER BY YearOfMortgrage) AS PreviousIndex 

From #Index

) as A

ORDER BY YearOfMortgrage ASC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum.  Assuming the values are all greater than 0, you can use some arithmetic:

```
select i.*,
       exp(sum(log(Percentage)) over (order by YearOfMortgrage)) as running_product
from #Index i;
```

Comment: As usual ... BRILLIANT

Comment: that is , thank you so much . this really made my day .

Comment: Please how can i insert the result into a database . because i want to convert the exponentional values to numeric before inserting. but i am not able to do that . Any help please Gordon Linoff